# ${BASH_SOURCE[1]} equivalent in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

I am trying to get the directory of the sourced script, and an important requirement is that sourcing can be nested, and the deepest script is sourced with something like `source <(cat file)`, so the directory should be taken for the second deepest file, which is easy to do in Bash with `${BASH_SOURCE[1]}`. Any idea how to do the same in Zsh?

#### UPDATE:

(From my comment below) The difference between ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} and ${BASH_SOURCE[1]} matters a lot in this case, because the script is sourced with <(...), and ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} doesn't point to a real file, but to a temporary file descriptor instead, which is why I need to get the second deepest file in the source chain.

Comment: Good spotting!!

Comment: @Inian, lol, I'd have reasons to be concerned about my mental health if I were asking the same question that I myself had answered not long ago XD. My answer there applies to ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} equivalent, not ${BASH_SOURCE[1]}. The difference matters a lot in this case, because the script is sourced with <(...), and ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} doesn't point to a real file, but to a temporary file descriptor instead, which is why I need to get the second deepest file in the source chain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `funcfiletrace` parameter defined by the `zsh/parameter` module.

> *`funcfiletrace`*
>
> This array contains the **absolute line numbers and corresponding file names** for the point where the current function, **sourced file**, or (if `EVAL_LINENO` is set) eval command was called.
>
> The array is of the same length as `funcsourcetrace` and `functrace`, but differs from `funcsourcetrace` in that the line and file are the point of call, not the point of definition, and differs from `functrace` in that all values are absolute line numbers in files, rather than relative to the start of a function, if any.

Use the last element of this array.

### Example

Consider the following files structure:

```
foo
└── bar
    ├── baz
    │   └── baz.zsh
    └── foo.zsh
```

and files content:

#### foo.zsh

```sh
file="$(print -P ${(%):-%x})"
dir="${file:h}"

echo "foo file: $file"
echo "foo directory: $dir"

source <(cat "$dir/baz/baz.zsh")
```

#### baz.zsh

```sh
zmodload zsh/parameter

file="$funcfiletrace[$#funcfiletrace]"
dir="${file:h}"

echo "foo file from bar: $file"
echo "foo directory from bar: $dir"
```

#### Result

```
% zsh foo/bar/foo.zsh
foo file: foo/bar/foo.zsh
foo directory: foo/bar
foo file from bar: foo/bar/foo.zsh:7
foo directory from bar: foo/bar
```

Comment: Your exact code didn't work for nested sourcing, but what ended up working for me was `${funcfiletrace[1]%:*}`, which seems to produce the same result as `${BASH_SOURCE[1]}` in Bash. Thank you for your help!